# Packer tool Provisioners Query - Executing Shell Script on Installed Packer Machine

Tags: packer

I have packer tool installed on Linux Machine. I am provisioning a Windows machine through this tool. I want to execute one shell script which will initiate a scan on provisioned VM in order to check the vulnerability. I added shell script in the provisioner section of the packer JSON and the shell script was working fine when I was provisioning Linux VM. Now I am facing issues while provisioning Windows VM. I don't want to write any powershell script in order to initiate the Scan. Is there any way to execute the shell script from the machine where packer is installed after windows VM gets provisioned. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`shell-local`](https://packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell-local.html) provisioner to run tools on the Packer host. The only problem is to get the IP of the VM you want to scan. How to do that depends on which builder you are using.

Comment: I also tried using shell-local but it is also not working. Below is my packer JSON

Comment: Below is my packer JSON     {"Amazon":{"Windows":{"variables":{"var_source_ami":"","var_new_aminame":""},"builders":[{"type":"amazon-ebs","region":"------------","instance_type":"t2.micro","source_ami":"{{user `var_source_ami`}}","ami_name":"{{user `var_new_aminame`}}","subnet_id":"-------------","iam_instance_profile":"Packer_Role","user_data_file":"/usr/local/packer/template/bootstrap_win.txt","communicator":"winrm","winrm_username":"Administrator","winrm_password":"SuperS3cr3t!"}],"provisioners":[{"type":"shell","command":"echo foo"}]}}}

Comment: My local machine is linux where packer tool is installed and I am provisioning a windows machine. I want to first provision the windows machine, create the AMI and then execute some command in local linux machine before provisioned VM is terminated.

Comment: I am getting this error in the logs. Failed to initialize builder 'amazon-ebs'. type provisioner not found.

Comment: If you need help getting started with Packer it's better to send a email to the packer-tool mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @Rickard for your help. shell-local has worked now. I am having one query. I want to pass runtime argument in my shell-local script. Will that work and how can I consume that argument in shell script. Here is my provisioner snippet                                                                         "provisioners": [
        {
          "type": "shell-local",
          "environment_vars": [
            "test_user={{user `test_user`}}",
            "test_password={{user `test_password`}}"
          ],
          "command": "sh /home/abcteam/12-Jan/test.sh"
        }
      ]

Comment: Just read the env vars in your script instead of passing them as arguments. It's a more generic solution.

Comment: "command": "sh /home/abcteam/12-Jan/test.sh  '{{user 'test_password'}}'" . In this line I am passing test_password value in the command itself. how can I get this in test.sh script ? When running the packer JSON I can see output in the logs as Executling local command: sh /home/abcteam/12-jan/test.sh 'dummypassword'. I tried to get this in script using $1 but failed. Any solution for this ?